# Sharepoint lists: Specific users have access to specific columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Is there a way to make a column only visible to certain people? I want to hide a couple columns from the main users of my list/power app.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to hide columns from list form or list view?

Comment: Both I guess, Just dont want users to see a couple columns. From the power app front end to the sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:**

Create different views for each type of audience, with which you could select the columns you want to show.
Views can be specified when sending a link of the list or when adding the list to a SharePoint page.

The problem with this solution is that users could still select other views and see the content of all columns.

[More on how to create views.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)

**solution 2:**

Create multiple lists and connect them using Power Automate, so that by creating an item in one list, the same item would be automatically (or with a button) copied to the other lists.

By limiting user access on these lists, it is possible to have users that can only view the specified content of each item.

[More on how to use Power Automate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view and and select the special columns that can only be viewed by specific users. Navigate to that view, and "**Edit**" the page. Then, edit the List View Web Part, expand "**Advanced**", and add your **audience**. This does not hide the view in the drop-down however.

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[SharePoint audience targeting – Everything you need to know](https://www.spguides.com/sharepoint-audience-targeting/)

[Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)

Comment: Is this the same as Microsoft lists?

Comment: This is classic/old experience. Audience targeting is not available for list web parts in modern experience.